# d3 axis rendering outside the SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm adding two axis to an SVG, however, the y axis is rendered off the left of the SVG:

[image: Y Axis off to the left edge]

If I set the orientation to 'right' then it's rendered, but on the left hand side:

[image: Y Axis present]

The code is like this:

```
'use strict';

var margins = {top: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50, right: 50};
var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%d-%b-%y')
var svg = d3.select('.graph');

var svgWidth = parseInt(svg.style('width')),
    svgHeight = parseInt(svg.style('height'));

var height = svgHeight - margins.top - margins.bottom,
    width = svgWidth - margins.left - margins.right;

var dates = [], closes = [];

data.forEach(function(item) {
    dates.push(dateFormat.parse(item.date));
    closes.push(item.close);
});

var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]).domain([d3.min(dates), d3.max(dates)]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, d3.max(closes)]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom');
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('right');

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default position of any `g` is `(0, 0)` and `.orient('left')` means that the axis is placed to the *left* of `(0, 0)`, which is outside the scene. You need to manually set the `transform` on the `g` element which contains the axis:

```
yAxis.orient('left');
svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'y axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [margins.left, margins.top] + ')');
  .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Any tips on working out the width of the axis? e.g. `1.0` requires much less padding than `1,000.00`

Comment: @Ian Unfortunately, nothing other than "rendering" all the ticks (either to string and then using a max-width, or actually rendering to them `<text>` off-screen and looking at their BoundingBox), finding the maximum space needed and then *.update*-ing all the components of the chart. This usually performs _well enough_ to be usable, but is often too much trouble if the ticks don't change much.

Comment: thanks - yeah I noticed when using `dimple.js` it had issues like that. Guess I'll have to work it out manually!

Answer (score 4):

I'd look closer at some of the [tried](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) and [true](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) examples.

With the recommended form you are missing a "drawing area" `g` element.

```
// have an SVG that is the drawing area width/height plus margins
// you don't show your mark-up but it looks like your code is ok 

// append a `g` element and translate it to your margins
// you'll do all your drawing to the g element
svg = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

// append axis to this g
// your y-axis will be in the margin, so adjust margins.left to fit
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```